# Set data attribute in html element when slide is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

hy,

im using FlexSlider to my web site (Slider w/thumbnail controlNav pattern), I made some modification of style of thumbnail, my question is how can i set data-thumb attribute in li element when the slider is active, in css they juste change the opacity of img i want to change the src image this the class css

```
  .flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
```

html code

```
<div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">

                <li data-thumb="assets/img/nav-slide.png">
                  <img src="assets/img/sld2.jpg" />
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
```

there is any way to set data-thumb using css3, i want to be for example like this when the slide thumbnail in mode active

```
 <div class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">

                <li data-thumb="assets/img/active-nav-slide.png">
                  <img src="assets/img/sld2.jpg" />
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if ($('.flex-control-thumbs').hasClass('active'))
{
    $(this).find('li').attr('data-thumb', 'assets/img/active-nav-slide.png');
}
```

Comment: thanks Voque for your respond, this is what i want i have juste try it but its didn't work i put this code in the bottom of my html page  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
      if ($('.flex-control-thumbs').hasClass('flex-active'))
      {
          $(this).find('li').attr('data-thumb', 'assets/img/active-nav-slide.png');
      }
</script>